# Rapid clicking creates too many requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch-api

I'm doing a small just-for-fun-project (a pokedex) using react and pokeAPI.

In the application a user can click on a pokemon and the app will fetch that pokemon and show additional info in a modal box.

The problem is this: In the modal box, i have made left and right arrows to change to the previous and next pokemons, if a user is clicking rapidly on one of the arrows, a call to the api is made every time and when the clicking stops, the user has to wait for all the previous promises to resolve.

I don't want to disable the method or the buttons while loading, because it should possible to run through the pokemon. I basically just want to reject a previous promise, if a new one is made. Is this possible?

Here is the method that fetches a pokemon:

```
showDetails(pokemon){
//check if the pokemon is already is state
const statePokemon = this.state.pokemon.find(p => {
   return p.name === pokemon;
});
if(!statePokemon) {
  //set loading and pass the pokemon as a string
  //to show which pokemon is being fetched
  this.setState({
    pokemonLoading : true,
    pokemonFetched : false,
    showing : pokemon,
  });
  let pokemonArr = [...this.state.pokemon];
  let newPokemon = {};
  fetch(`http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    pokemonArr.push(response);
    newPokemon = response;
  })
  .then((_) => {
    //don't update state with new pokemon
    //if user has closed modal while loading
    if (this.state.showing) {
      this.setState({
        pokemon : pokemonArr,
        pokemonLoading : false,
        pokemonFetched : true,
        showing : newPokemon,
      });
    }
  });
} else {
  //set showing with pokemon from state
  //without making a new fetch
  this.setState({
    showing : statePokemon,
    pokemonFetched : true,
  });
}
```

}

The repo for the project is [here](https://github.com/MortenSaabye/PokeDex)

Hope you guys can help!

Comment: Have you looked into debounce?

Comment: You could avoid making a new request when loading, but keep track of the pokemon they requested.  When the server response gets back if it isn't for the latest pokemon they requested, fire off a request for the latest.

Comment: [this might be nice](https://github.com/bvaughn/debounce-decorator), allows you to throw a little decorator over your class method, haven't tried it myself though

Comment: try cancellable prmise. http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html

Comment: @IrkenInvader sounds like a simple solution. I'm gonna try that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a debounce function. This will allow the function to only run so many times within a given period of time.

```
function debounce(fn, wait) {
  let timeout;
  return (...args) => {
    const waitFn = () => {
      timeout = clearTimeout(timeout);
      fn(...args);
    };
    if (!timeout) {
      timeout = setTimeout(waitFn, wait);
    }
  };
}

// this will run the showDetails function only once every 500ms
this.showDetails = debounce(this.showDetails.bind(this), 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

In additiona to @realseanp's answer, you could try throttling

```
function throttle(duration, fn) {
  let inProgress;
  return () => {
    if (inProgress) {
      clearTimeout(inProgress);
    }
    inProgress = setTimeout(fn, duration);
  };
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', throttle(500, () => console.log('keydown')), false);
```